# How to add extra property to a existing control in WPF application?

Tags: wpf, properties, controls

here is a question about a WPF application. I'm a self taught new programmer. I want to add a custom property in already existing image control in WPF.
Here is my XAML image control as

```
 <Image x:Name="cardMPOne" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MouseDown="moveCard"  Height="220" Margin="-300,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="100"/>
```

I want to add some string or integer properties like CardType="Heart" CardColor="red" CardValue = "1" etc.
How this can be achieved...
Thanks in advance.
Your answer will be appreciated..

Comment: You can inherit the control and add your own properties or use attached properties.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.Please provide me an example right here or a well explained link.

Comment: I believe google can help you better than me with the keywords I mentioned above. Anyways [Attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).